# Getting primary key from the database

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, c#-4.0, frontend

I created a method that traverses the data returned from the primary key in a repeat structure but the following error occurs, Can not implicitly convert type "System.Attribute" to "bool"

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.ComponentModel;
  using System.Data.SqlClient;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Reflection;
   using System.Web;




   UPDATE
 private void SetSelf(Cliente Entity)
    {

        foreach (PropertyInfo pro in Entity.GetType().GetProperties())
        {

             if (this.GetType().GetProperty(pro.Name).GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DataObjectFieldAttribute != null))
            this.GetType().GetProperty(pro.Name).SetValue(this, pro.GetValue(Entity));

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this line: `this.GetType().GetProperty(pro.Name).GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DataObjectFieldAttribute)` will return a `System.Attribute`, but the `if` is looking for a `bool`.

Don't you want to add a check ?

```
if (this.GetType().GetProperty(pro.Name).GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DataObjectFieldAttribute) != null){
}
```

Comment: I was able to solve the problem, I was putting the different of null before the closure of typeof relatives, I placed after the closure of the relatives and worked thanks for the help